# Incremental number animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a homepage that showing the value of incomes and expenses. Right now the values just appear on the the screen, however is was wondering whether i can make those number start from 0 and then have an animation to increment that value, like a stopwatch. Is it also possible to make the final number after the increment has finished to animate with a pulse". This is how i am making the label pulsate now but the label becomes bigger from the left had side and not from the center.

```
[self.view addSubview:_lblTotal];

    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaleAnimation.duration = 0.4;
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    scaleAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

    [_lblTotal.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];
```

[image: homepage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is possible.

add a variable with the number to increment

```
@property (nonatomic) double currentValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

initialize it in viewDidLoad

```
_currentValue = 0.00;
```

write a function `updateNumber`

```
-(void)updateNumber {
    _currentValue = _currentValue + 0.01;
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", _currentValue]];

    if(_currentValue >= 100.0) {  //example to stop incrementation on 100
         _timer = nil;  // stop the timer
         // do your animation
    }

}
```

in your `viewDidAppear()` or whenever you want to start the counting like this

```
if(_timer == nil) {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0  //seconds
            target:self
            selector:@selector(updateNumber)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:true];
}
```

Comment: How would I cater for decimal numbers? I want the counter to stop when it reaches a certain value, e.g 338.00 in the image in the question

Comment: @John a bit of self imagination will be necessary ;) i updated my answer anyways to include decimals. Just use a float or double instead of the integer.

Comment: I have tried this method but the project crashes. Saying unrecognised selector sent to instance. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: not without source code. dont just copy/paste my code. try to understand it and adapt it to your personal project. you will not learn anything if you just copy/paste solutions ;) Try it without the `:` on `@selector(updateNumber)`

Comment: I have managed to fix that error as i typed updateNumber in the timer incorrectly. I somewhat understand how it works however i am confused why the numbers do not increment. When i change repeats:NO to yes the label updates, but when it is NO the label changes to 0.01 once then stops. Is this because it is not calling the updateNumber method again?

Comment: of course it has to be YES. if it is NO, it will only increment once :)

Answer (score 2):

The following open source UILabel subclass does the scrolling numbers bit you are looking for.

https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel

Example of the type of usage is:

```
myLabel.method = UILabelCountingMethodLinear;
[myLabel countFrom:50 to:100 withDuration:5.0f];
```

I would look to see how that is done and then extend it to add the pulse at the end once the animation for the counting has completed.

Comment: Why the -1. This link has code which does exactly what the question asks for. That being animation of a label containing a number (int or float) from a start to end number with a given duration and animation style!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I speculate that the downvote is because this answer will be useless if that project goes away. Answers should provide some useful information event without outside links. Links should supplement answers, not be the sole content.

Comment: Also, [Apple reserves all two-letter prefixes like `UI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW4). Using the `UI` prefix on a non-Apple class is particularly egregious.

Comment: @robmayoff Understand. Did not have time to dismantle the code at the link, but posted as it does what is required. As for use of the letters UI, not my code 8^).

Comment: You could post the link as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to separate the incrementing number and the pulse animation into two different questions.

On the question of the pulse, the code is correct but the reason it scales off-center is probably due to your view's frame which is bigger than its content, which appears to be right-aligned rather than centered.

If you make `_lblTotal`'s frame fit the content, by calling `[_lblTotal sizeToFit];` your pulse animation should work as expected. But then this assumes that you do the right-alignment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is an example  code , which will surely help you but you have to customize the timing as it certainly suit my need:-*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    currentValueAmount=0; //provide initial value for your incremented label
     targetFloatAmount=1300;//provide the target value up-to which the value will be incremented.
    self.lblAmount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentValueAmount];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateIncrementLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f]; // give some delay as per your choice as to load the whole UI first and then calling the method to increment.
}

-(void)animateIncrementLabel
{


    self.lblAmount.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.000f, 0.000f);
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.001 //calling timer , if the label value is very small then increase the no of Zero's for example 0.00001

                                             target: self

                                           selector: @selector(handleTimer:)

                                           userInfo: nil

                                            repeats: YES];
    //animating the incremented text with some transform and bounce
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.1 delay:0.2f usingSpringWithDamping:0.4 initialSpringVelocity:0.3 options:0 animations:^{

        self.lblAmount.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);

        }];


}

- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer
{
    if(currentValueAmount>targetFloatAmount)
    {

        self.lblAmount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",targetFloatAmount];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.2f usingSpringWithDamping:0.4 initialSpringVelocity:0.3 options:0 animations:^{

            self.lblAmount.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

        }];
    }


    else
    {
        currentValueAmount=currentValueAmount+0.0008;
        self.lblAmount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentValueAmount];



    }
}
```

Comment: HI, i have tried this method and my project crashes. Any Idea why? unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Which line it is crashing

Comment: I have just customized a little part of my code, to make you understand.. otherwise it is working fine from my end. @John